# Find Architecture Explorer in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, uml

I am unable to create Class diagram with dependencies.

I find all class diagrams but without any dependencies. I tried to find solution for it. Then i get Architecture Explorer -> New UML Diagram ->  something.

What i tried next to create dependent class diagram.

I have to mentioned it into Project Doc.

Thanks.

Comment: Your English is difficult to understand. I don't understand what you mean about dependencies *between* class diagrams. That's not how UML works. Are you saying that you are unable to create a dependency *on* a class diagram?

Comment: I have multiple classes and their diagrams. All they are get separated but i want them all with dependencies means inherited / collaboration etc.

Comment: Sorry, your comment makes very little sense to me. Do you have a friend who is better at English?

Comment: Ok Np. Can you find that Where is Architecture Explorer located in Visual Studio 2012?